# Swift how to add tap gesture on uicollectionviewcell's child elements

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewcell in my code

```
let cell = commentSection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CommentCell
```

And in `CommentCell` i have got this imageview

```
let likeIcon: UIImageView = {
    let imv = UIImageView()
    imv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "like")
    imv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imv
}()
```

I tried adding a tap gesture to `likeIcon` in `CommentCell` and also in `cellForItemAt` but none of them triggered it when clicking.How can i add `gestureTapRecognizer` to child element of cell?

Comment: Do you have `imv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` ?

Comment: @Phyber Nope,i'll add it now

Comment: @Phyber it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code:

```
....
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    recognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourHandleMethod(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
....

func yourHandleMethod(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tap")
}
```

Call this method `update()` outside in `cellForItem` (for every cell).

```
...
    cell.update()
...
```

// This method inside cell

```
func update() {
    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    recognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourHandleMethod(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}
```

Comment: Have you added your likeIcon to cell like addSubview(likeIcon) ?

Comment: make "let likeIcon" -> "lazy var likeIcon", if you create recognizer in the initialization code of likeIcon

Comment: I change it to lazy var now when i click the method that is in `cellForItemAt ` gets executed and it only gets executed when i click on top of the first cell

Comment: Yes, i know what the problem is... You have to add own recognizer for every imageView.

Comment: cellForRow is for UITableView did you mean cellforitem?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant cellForItem

Comment: It didn't work.I changed UIImageView to button as suggested at the bottom but it has the same problem.I removed all elements and constraints to check may be there is an overlap,still it only work when clicking on the first cell's button's top

Comment: I'll try to create that element separately and then add it to cell in cellForItemAtt

Answer (score 0):

Adding **UIImageView** and providing gesture recognizer will increase the complexity of your development.
If you need action then use **UIButton** and set target action for button in cellForRowAtIndex

You can set either `background image` or `image` to **UIButton**.

Better keep processed image in UIImage object and assign it to UIButton.